# can't cast to my custom ConfigurationSection

Tags: c#, .net, configuration-files

I'm trying to read a config file like this:

```
var dllPath =  System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.
    GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
dllPath = dllPath.Replace("file:\\", string.Empty);
var configPath = string.Format(@"{0}\..\contentFolders.config", dllPath);
var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap() {ExeConfigFilename = configPath};
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, 
    ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var contentFolderConfig = 
    (ContentFolderSettings)config.GetSection("contentFolderConfiguration");
```

I have `ContentFolderSettings` defined in the `Corp.Common` project and it inherits from `ConfigurationSection`.  Here is the contents of `contentFolders.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <section name="contentFolderConfiguration"
    type="Corp.Common.ContentFolderSettings, Corp.Common"
    requirePermission="false"/>
  <contentFolderConfiguration>
    <contentFolders>
      <contentFolder key="ImagesFolder" path="content\images"/>
      <contentFolder key="CssFolder" path="content\css"/>
      ...
    </contentFolders>
  </contentFolderConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

But the line calling `config.GetSection()` is throwing `InvalidCastException` on:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.DefaultSection' to type 
'Corp.Common.ContentFolderSettings'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tag is missing**

In my case was this:

```
<configSections>
```

so you just add the tag

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tag is missing .

Contains configuration section and namespace declarations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903350(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: that link doesn't provide any answer to this question